# Issue in writing a wrapper to printf in C to implement a flushed printf?

Tags: c, printf

I want to use printf for some basic debugging (Yes, I am familiar with gdb, etc.).  As printf buffers, a call to fflush(stdout) is required immediately after a printf. I thought of writing a simple wrapper. So the wrapper will be something like this:

```
   flushedPrintf(int noArgs, args to be passed to printf);
```

I think that the implementation of such a function would be something like this:

```
   void flushedPrintf(int noArgs, args to be passed to printf) {

       char *myString = malloc(MAX_LENGTH_DEFINED);
       sprintf(myString, ....args to be passed to printf);

       printf("%s", myString);
       fflush(stdout);

   }
```

I know there are functions/macros like va_list, va_start and va_args but those will require me to parse the printf format string to get the type and I want to avoid doing that. Is there a simple approach? As this is only for debugging purpose, I do not mind having the format type restricted to %d, %f and %s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `setvbuf` and set the stream to be line buffered.

```
setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IOLBL, 0);
```

> Is there a simple approach?

Sure, just forward the arguments.

```
void flushedPrintf(const char *fmt, ...) {
   va_list va;
   va_start(va, fmt);
   vprintf(fmt, va);
   va_end(va);
   fflush(stdout);
   // TODO: propagate return value from vprintf and fflush
}
```

All standard `*printf` functions have `v*printf` alternatives that accept a `va_list` argument. If you didn't know about them [here is a nice reference on cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/vfprintf).

> here are functions/macros like va_list, va_start and va_args but those will require me to parse the printf format string to get the type

That's wrong - using `va_*` macros do not require you to parse `printf` format string.

Comment: printf returns int. wrapper should do the same

Comment: @P__J__ That's my error. I had asked so in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Use stderr and fprintf. Stderr is unbuffered by default.

This question is answered in better detail here:

[Why does printf not flush after the call unless a newline is in the format string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716296/why-does-printf-not-flush-after-the-call-unless-a-newline-is-in-the-format-strin)

Answer (score 1):

As an extension (and maybe some correction) to the @KamilCuk answer.

If you use gcc family compiler you can use the special function attribute showing the compiler that the function is printf-like.  The compiler will analyse the format string and emit the warnings - same as when using printf.

```
int flushedPrintf(const char *fmt, ...) __attribute__((format(printf, 1, 2)));
int flushedPrintf(const char *fmt, ...) 
{
   int result;
   va_list va;
   va_start(va, fmt);
   result = vprintf(fmt, va);
   va_end(va);
   fflush(stdout);
   return result;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/SbGRxk